# WPF DependencyProperty throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I am trying to set a dependency property which is updated by a WCF callback thread.
There is a ProgressBar on MainWindow.xaml that is bound to this property:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar" Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

MainWindow has an instance of DemoModule, which is defined as:

**DemoModule.xaml.cs**

```
/// <summary>
///     Interaction logic for DemoModule.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class DemoModule : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Progress", typeof(int), typeof(DemoModule));        
    public event ProgressEventHandler ProgressChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Progress
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ProgressProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProgressProperty, value); }  // setter throws InvalidOperationException "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DemoModule" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public DemoModule()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ProgressChanged += OnProgressChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [progress changed].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="args">The <see cref="ProgressChangedEventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.</param>
    public void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Current Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Debug.WriteLine("Current Dispatcher Thread: {0}", Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread.ManagedThreadId);

        if (ProgressChanged == null) return;

        Debug.WriteLine("ProgressChangedEventArgs.Current: " + args.Current);
        Progress = Convert.ToInt32(args.Current * 100);
        OnPropertyChanged("Progress");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [property changed].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Property " + propertyName + " changed. Value = " + Progress);
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

The `Progress.set()` is throwing an exception because of the thread affinity.
How can I fix this?

**Update 1**

This is allegedly thread safe, but has no effect:

```
public int Progress
{
    get
    {
        return Dispatcher.Invoke((() => (int)GetValue(ProgressProperty))); 
    }
    set
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => SetValue(ProgressProperty, value)));
    }
 }
```

**Update 2**

My DemoModule.xaml.cs has a reference to a client library which implements the WCF callback method OnUpdateProgress:

**InstallerAgentServiceClient.cs**

```
public void OnUpdateProgress(double progress)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine("Progress: " + progress*100 + "%");
            var args = new ProgressChangedEventArgs(progress, 1, "Installing");
            _installModule.OnProgressChanged(this, args);
        }
```

The `_installModule` object above is the instance of `DemoModule`.

**Update 3**

After removing the `[CallBackBehavior]` attribute from the WCF client library, there no longer seems to be thread synchronization issues. I can update the progress bar in the MainWindow as follows:

**DemoModule.xaml.cs**

```
public void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Progress = Convert.ToInt32(args.Current * 100);
    var progressBar = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("ProgressBar") as ProgressBar;
    if (progressBar != null)
        progressBar.Value = Progress;
}
```

Comment: Why do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged? You don't need it if you are binding to DependencyProperties.

Comment: I thought I had to do both. Still learning here. My first week with WPF.

Comment: Well actually there are two possibilities for VM implementation. The first one is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. The second is to inherit from DependencyObject and to declare the properties as Dependency properties. The first one is usually the most appropriate. However ViewModel should not inherit from WPF controls like UserControl ... well except perhaps some specific cases.

Comment: Since we can't do multiple inheritance, I guess I will have to stick with INPC.

Comment: Show your WCF call to update the progress bar.

Comment: @lll See Update 2 above.

Comment: Where's the `Thread` that spawned InstallerAgentServiceClient? How was is started

Comment: There is no explicit thread. I'm guessing the WCF callback channel runs on its own thread.

Comment: It looks like `[CallbackBehavior]` was affecting which thread the callback was running on. Removing it allowed me to set the ProgressBar's value. See Update 3 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommand using the IProgress interface.
Works like a charm for me and is pretty easy to use.
In your progressbarVM add

```
public double Actualprogress
{
get { return (double)GetValue(ActualprogressProperty); }
set { SetValue(ActualprogressProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualprogressProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Actualprogress", typeof(double), typeof(ProgressBar), 
new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
```

then call your method as an asyn task using await like so :

```
var progress = new Progress<double>(progressPercent => 
progressBarVM.progressBar.Actualprogress = progressPercent);
Parser parser = new Parser();
ModelVMResult result = await Task.Run(() => parser.Parse(filename,progress));
```

then in your method "parse" just do:

```
float threshold = 0.0f;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
if (i >= threshold)
{ progress.Report(prog += 1); threshold += count / 100.0f; }
this.Readline(reader, i);
}
```

Of course you need to bind your xaml progressbar.Value to ProgressbarVM.Actualprogress.
Then your progressbar will update and your app will still be responsive during the process.

Answer (score 6):

You need to update your DepedencyProperty via the UI Thread. Use:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Action)
```

Or:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Action)
```

Comment: I tried that, and `this.Dispatcher.Invoke()`. Neither had any effect on the ProgressBar.